# Remove yellow upgrade footer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, infowindow

QGIS 3 is out but doesn't have the plugins I need yet so I'll use QGIS 2.18 a bit longer. I have QGIS 3.2 installed alongside to test the new features.

However, there is now a footer in QGIS 2.18 telling me there is a new version and I should upgrade.

Is there a way to get rid of the yellow footer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should uncheck `"Check QGIS version at startup"` option

In `"Settings > Options... > General > Application"` tab

for QGIS 2.x
[image: qgis2.x]

and for QGIS 3.x
[image: qgis3.x]